# How to automatically extract a file from an IP address and port number

Tags: javascript, android, network-programming, ip

Is there any Javascript to automatically extract a file given a file name and the IPaddress/port where the file is stored?
I have two PC's(static IP) connected to my home router.I have transferred one file(let's say an JPEG image) from PC1 to PC2. Now, from PC1, I want extract that Image from PC2.

Comment: you want to save it or just to show it?

Comment: I want to save that file on the PC which actually sent that file. Actually I am trying to see it in my android phone through an android apps.

Comment: I have made an android apps which connects to a DDNS server and get back the IP address and port of the device to be used. Now I have placed let's say an Image in a PC(which points to the IP address returned by DDNS server). I want to download that file to my Android phone when DDNS server return back the IP address and port no. For simplicity., I just want to place a Image in PC which is connected to my Home router. Now, through my Nexus 4 Apps, I want to get that Image and see it on my Phone. I didn't get how can I do this.